# Unit testing a Web API controller actualResult using moq does not behave as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq

Unit testing a controller returning `IHttpActionResult` causes

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid myId)
{    
    var myaccount = await _myaccountService.GetMyAccount(myId);
    return Ok(myaccount);
}
```

In Test Method the code

```
var actualResult = (await controller.Get(It.IsAny<Guid>()) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<MyAccount>>).Content;
```

Returns

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GeMyAccount_Returns_CorrectData()
{
      // Arrange         
      var expectedResult = new List<MyAccount>
     {
         new  MyAccount
          {
           Id = "1",
           Name = "Name1"
          },
         new  MyAccount
          {
           Id = "2",
           Name = "Name2"
          },
     };

    //Act 
    var mockMyAccountService = new Mock<IMyAccountService>();
    mockMyAccountService.Setup(mock => 
    mock.GetMyAccount(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(expectedResult));
    var controller = new MyAccountController(mockMyAccountService.Object);

     var actualResult = (await controller.Get(It.IsAny<Guid>()) as 
    OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<MyAccount>>).Content;
    mockOnrAccountService.Verify(m => m.GetMyAccount(It.IsAny<Guid>()));
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetMyAccount` method in `mockMyAccountService` is expected a `List<MyAccount>` as a return type. From that, the `Get` method of `MyAccountController` is also expected to return a type of `OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<MyAccount>>` instead of `OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<MyAccount>>`. So, the problem is in your incorrect type cast.